# QGis: icon defined in metadata.txt does not show in the plugin manage & install menu

Tags: windows, macos, plugins, icons, qgis

I made several QGis plugins. I created icons (files named icon.png, saved in the plugins directory folder root), and compiled the resource file (`make clean; make`). The icon path is saved in metadata.txt as:

```
icon=icon.png
```

The icons show in the toolbar.
On Window computers, icons do not show not when selecting the plugins from the "Manage and install Plugins menu", but they show under Mac OS X!
I tried with different version of Windows, with QGis 2.10 and 2.12, different plugins, same problem.
I suppose this has nothing to do with the compilation of resource. Do I need to do something special for the path?

I noticed the following: only plugins installed as a DLL have their icons shown by the plugin manager.

[image: Plugin manager does not show icon under Windows]
[image: Plugin manager show icon under Mac OS X]

Comment: I don't know =(. But you might try looking here: https://github.com/g-sherman/Qgis-Plugin-Builder/tree/master/plugin_templates to see if you can get the correct behavior with those example plugins and then decipher how they are doing it.

Comment: Just a stab in the dark - make sure you're using the correct path separator. "\" in Windows vs. "/" in Unix